# InfluxDB V2 OSS Alerts : capturing the metric value in notification message

Tags: monitoring, influxdb-2

We are monitoring a bunch of IoT Devices using TIG stack and are trying to configure alerts using InfluxDB V2's inbuilt Alerts feature. We have configured the slack notification channel and we would like to capture the metric value as part of the message. Here is a sample status message template:

```
The memory utilization is *${ r._level }* 
On Device Name: *${ r.host }*
Polled At: *${ r._time}*
```

This shows the alert like this:

```
Memory Alert  The memory utilization is crit
On Device Name: Device-dev-02
Polled At: 2021-09-16T06:41:15.000000000Z
```

The actual value is in the field `_value`, when I try to capture this as part of the message

```
The memory utilization is *${ r._level }* 
On Device Name: *${ r.host }*
Polled At: *${ r._time}*
Current Memory: *${ r._value}*
```

The notification check fails. I read in the [documentation](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v2.0/monitor-alert/checks/create/#flux-only-interpolates-string-values) that Flux only interpolates string values, I tried to convert the _value to string

```
The memory utilization is *${ r._level }* 
On Device Name: *${ r.host }*
Polled At: *${ r._time}*
Current Memory: *${string(v: r._value)}*
```

Still the notification check fails.

Are we missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get this question answered, [thanks to Jay from Influxdata community](https://community.influxdata.com/t/influxdb-v2-oss-alerts-capturing-the-metric-value-in-notification-message/21730/3?u=yogirk). Posting the answer here, hopefully someone might find it useful.

When creating a check the _value field is automatically pivoted. In short this means instead of using the `_value` field you should use the `_fieldname`.

For example:

```
Check: ${ r._check_name } is: ${ r._level } ${string(v: r.used_percent)}
```

Where by `used_percent` was the _field name.